# How to get rank according to count in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, count

I am getting issue with fetching the rank according to the count.

I have two tables :

```
1)images
2)images_like
```

Now if the images_like have no entries then it is showing "NULL" in the ranks. please check the query  and output :

```
SELECT im.id, 
   rank 
FROM   (SELECT image_id, 
               @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank, 
               Count(*)               AS cnt 
        FROM   images_like, 
               (SELECT @rownum := 0) r 
        GROUP  BY image_id 
        ORDER  BY `cnt` DESC) AS d 
       RIGHT JOIN images AS im 
               ON d.image_id = im.id
```

[image]

i need to display 3 not null ....

Thanks in advance !!!!!

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query - incidentally, note that RIGHT JOINs are vanishingly rare.

Comment: kindly provide the sample data in your tables

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
SELECT im.id, d.rank  
FROM
(               
    SELECT t.image_id, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank 
    FROM
        (               
          SELECT image_id, 
                 Count(*) AS cnt 
          FROM   images_like
          GROUP  BY image_id 
          ORDER  BY `cnt` DESC) AS d       
        ) t, 
     (SELECT @rownum := 0) r          
) d     
RIGHT JOIN images AS im ON d.image_id = im.id
```